# Where to buy small AOI satellite images?

Tags: maxar-digitalglobe

I only need a 1 km^2 region VHR satellite images.

On distributor cites, I could only buy whole images for > 300$

For example, https://eos.com/landviewer

Is it possible to buy only small regions?

Answer (score 2):

I was going to put some options you might try but I found a [thread](https://support.google.com/earth/thread/8014237?hl=en) with a better compilation of commercial imagery sites:

- DigitalGlobe: https://www.digitalglobe.com/
- TerraServer, distributor for a number of satellite and aerial image providers: http://www.terraserver.com/
- Airbus Defence & Space: http://www.geo-airbusds.com/ (previously Astrium / Spot Image)
- Terrametrics: http://www.truearth.com/
- USGS: http://www.usgs.gov/pubprod/aerial.html
- Planet: https://www.planet.com/products/planet-imagery/
- Harris Geospatial Imagery: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Data-Imagery
- Satellite Imaging Corporation: http://www.satimagingcorp.com/gallery.html

You have not specified where your study area is nor what vendors you've already looked at, so I think this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you for your response!!!

I have looked at 

1) landinfo.com they answered "25km2 minimum order per image" 

2) eos.com/landviewer High-resolution imagery(for analytics) >300$ each

3) https://imagery.geocento.com/
The same staff. "Minimum area size is 25.0 km2."

I want only buy 1 km2 area. I heard that some new service launched half of the year before that you could sell small areas.
But I can't find this service anymore